# Output Multiselect TV by getResource in modx revo

Tags: multi-select, modx-revolution, getresource

I try to output Multiselect TV with list of rescources by getResource.

When I output the tv [[*myMultiselectTV]] with two or more id output like this - idid - without any commas. And when I use

```
[[getResources? 
   &resources=`[[*myMultiselectTV]]` 
   &tpl=`productsList`
   &includeTVs=`1`
   &debug=`1`
   &processTVs=`1`
  ]]
```

I dont get anything.

When I output the tv with one id, I get the only one id and with getResource it render ok.

How push my multiselectTV in getResource with commas between ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set commma as custom output type of your tv: [image]